# Build error in embedding python-(where I import the file)

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2010, python-2.7

I am a beginner in python and have an intermediate level knowledge about C++.
I am trying to embed python code in c++. However, I get a build error and with my current level of knowledge I am unable to troubleshoot it.Kindly help me in this regard.
Following is the code.

```
    #include <iostream> 
         using namespace std;
         #include <Python.h> 
         int main() 
        { 
        cout<<"Calling Python to find the sum of 2 and 2"; 
        // Initialize the Python interpreter. 
        Py_Initialize();
        // Create some Python objects that will later be assigned values. 

    PyObject *pName,*pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue; 
    // Convert the file name to a Python string.
     pName = PyString_FromString("Sample.py"); // Import the file as a Python module. 

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName); 
    // Create a dictionary for the contents of the module. 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule); 
    // Get the add method from the dictionary. 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "add"); 
    // Create a Python tuple to hold the arguments to the method. 
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(2); 
    // Convert 2 to a Python integer. 
    pValue = PyInt_FromLong(2); 
    // Set the Python int as the first and second arguments to the method. 

    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue); 
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue); 
    // Call the function with the arguments. 
    PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs); 
    // Print a message if calling the method failed. 
    if(pResult == NULL) 
    cout<<"Calling the add method failed.\n"; 
    // Convert the result to a long from a Python object. 
    long result = PyInt_AsLong(pResult); 
    // Destroy the Python interpreter. 
    Py_Finalize(); // Print the result. 
    cout<<"The result is"<<result; 
    cout<<"check";
    return 0; 

    }
```

I get the following error:
    **Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in pytest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.**
    and the build breaks at the line `pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);`
    the file Sample.py has the contents:

```
    # Returns the sum of two numbers.
    def add(a, b):
        return a+b
```

I am using python 2.7 and VS2010.I have created a win32 console project for this and I am building in release mode.I have copied the file Sample.py to the project folder.
I cannot figure out what's causing the build to crash.Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, indent your code, MSVC even has an option to do it automatically! After all, you want people here to read it, so go and clean that up. Then, don't declare variables without initializing them in C++. This makes it clear from where on you can use them. Lastly, whenever you call a function, check its results for errors. By default, just `throw std::runtime_error("foo() failed");` on errors. More elaborate, you could try to retrieve and add error information from Python.

Now, your immediate error is the use of a null pointer, which you would have avoided if you had checked returnvalues. After writing the code to correctly detect that error, the next thing I'd look at is the missing initialization of the Python interpreter. You already have a comment in place, but comments don't count. I guess that if you had implemented proper error handling, Python would also have told you about the missing initialization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.As I said, I am a beginner in python.Can you suggest any resource where I can learn about error handling.The python/C api assumes a lot of knowledge on the reader's part.